# PHP Twitter replace link and hashtag with real link

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am looping over JSON response from Twitter API. Each API response gives me a tweet similar to:

> Hi my name is @john, and I love #soccer, visit me

I am trying to replace `@john`, and insert `<a href=http://twitter.com/john>@john</a>` but the comma (`,`) after `@john`, is the problem.

How to replace dots, commas, etc before and after the tag?

Answer (score 11):

```
$str = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/i", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$1\">$0</a>", $str);
```

Comment: Sorry, SO didn't notify me someone has already posted an answer.

Answer (score 10):

Heres the function which converts hashtags, user mentions and urls to links, using 'entities' data on a tweet from Twitter API.

```
<?php

function tweet_html_text(array $tweet) {
    $text = $tweet['text'];

    // hastags
    $linkified = array();
    foreach ($tweet['entities']['hashtags'] as $hashtag) {
        $hash = $hashtag['text'];

        if (in_array($hash, $linkified)) {
            continue; // do not process same hash twice or more
        }
        $linkified[] = $hash;

        // replace single words only, so looking for #Google we wont linkify >#Google<Reader
        $text = preg_replace('/#\b' . $hash . '\b/', sprintf('<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%%23%2$s&src=hash">#%1$s</a>', $hash, urlencode($hash)), $text);
    }

    // user_mentions
    $linkified = array();
    foreach ($tweet['entities']['user_mentions'] as $userMention) {
        $name = $userMention['name'];
        $screenName = $userMention['screen_name'];

        if (in_array($screenName, $linkified)) {
            continue; // do not process same user mention twice or more
        }
        $linkified[] = $screenName;

        // replace single words only, so looking for @John we wont linkify >@John<Snow
        $text = preg_replace('/@\b' . $screenName . '\b/', sprintf('<a href="https://www.twitter.com/%1$s" title="%2$s">@%1$s</a>', $screenName, $name), $text);
    }

    // urls
    $linkified = array();
    foreach ($tweet['entities']['urls'] as $url) {
        $url = $url['url'];

        if (in_array($url, $linkified)) {
            continue; // do not process same url twice or more
        }
        $linkified[] = $url;

        $text = str_replace($url, sprintf('<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>', $url), $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: @DominicTobias there is an updated version here - https://github.com/alanbem/tweets2feed/blob/master/app/app.php#L34

Answer (score 4):

To do hash-tags do this

```
$item_content = preg_replace("/#([a-z_0-9]+)/i", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search/$1\">$0</a>", $item_content);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=http://twitter.com/$1>@$1</a>", $string)"
```