# Instagram replace hashtag with real link

Tags: regex, preg-replace, instagram, hashtag

I am trying to replace hashtag with a href and hashtag. I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3799463/1631551), and modified it for my needs, but it is ignoring text after dot `.`, and cut next letters:

**My function:**

```
function hashtag($str) {
    return preg_replace(array('/#(\w+)/', '/@(\w+)/'), array(' <a href="/t/$1" class="hashtag">#$1</a>', ' <a href="/u/$1" class="username">@$1</a>'), $str);
}
```

**Working example:**

```
@visual => <a href="/t/visual" class="hashtag">#visual</a>
```

**Not working example:**

```
@visual.test => <a href="/t/visual" class="hashtag">#visual</a>.test
```

How can I add `.` to the pattern to work it correctly and have this:

```
@visual.test => <a href="/t/visual.test" class="hashtag">#visual.test</a>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the regular expression, change `\w` to `[\w.]`

Comment: See Jan's answer below for the change I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, this is it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go for

```
function hashtag($str) {
    return preg_replace(
            array('/#(\w+)/', '/@([\w.]+)/'),
            #                     --^-- 
            array(' <a href="/t/$1" class="hashtag">#$1</a>', ' <a href="/u/$1" class="username">@$1</a>'), 
            $str);
}
```

Just put it in a character class, that is.

Comment: Working. Thanks a lot.